# Finding the asymptotes of the hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections

Find the asymptote of the hyperbola $(2x+3y-1)(kx-5y+2)+10=0....(1)$ .Also find the value of  $k$  for which the above equation will represent a rectangular hyperbola.

Now,i know that the asymptote of a hyperbola is $$y=\pm\frac{b}{a}(x-h)+k  $$
I tried to simplify the $(1)$ equation but could not go anywhere useful.Also set up the equation to zero to figure out the asymptote;failed in that road too.

Comment: The asymptotes are obtained by setting each bracket equal to zero. They are perpendicular when the product of the gradients is $-1$

Comment: The asymptotes are given by $(2x+3y-1)(kx-5y+2) = 0$

Comment: so, $(2x+3y-1)=0$ and  $(kx-5y+2)=0$ ?